# php - mkdir file outside web root directory permission

Tags: php

I am developing a web application with the file structure:

```
--->controllers
---> models
---> views
---> media uploads *issue directory*
---> html (web root)
     ----> index.php (guides to correct view)
```

Now here is the issue. To create the media uploads directory I had to change my document root permission to 777. Doesn't this create a security issue or am I safe (somewhat) because the file users interact with is isolated in the web root? if this is a security risk how can I allow myself to create files/directories without providing access to everyone? Also any other security advice or tutorials would be appreciated.

Mods sorry but a lot of the questions similar to this are old and I had no clue with people were still reading them. If there is a conversation type version of stacked overflow.

Comment: Security depends on what kind of filtering and checking you do before uploading files. IF .exe or any arbitrary file is allowed then security can be hampered.

Comment: I will already be checking that out. I meant if have the directories separated out like above. Will I have an issue with files being 0777?